# Sort by order in tool bar

Tags: magento-1.9, sorting

I have changed the default sort by to reference one of our attributes so the best sellers get listed first, It works perfectly via this code

```
public function setListOrders()
{
    $category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')
        ->getCurrentCategory();
    /* @var $category Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */
    $availableOrders = $category->getAvailableSortByOptions();
    unset($availableOrders['position']);
    $availableOrders = array_merge(array(
        'best_sellers' => $this->__('Best Seller'),
        'relevance' => $this->__('Relevance')
    ), $availableOrders);

    $this->getListBlock()
        ->setAvailableOrders($availableOrders)
        ->setDefaultDirection('desc')
        ->setSortBy('best_sellers');

    return $this;
}
```

As you can see i have set the direction to descending, However when ever i change the sort by attribute  (ie name, relevance or price) it changes the order to ascending, how can i change it so it always stays on descending unless the customer changes it?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar` and change variable `$_direction` value to `desc`

Comment: I have already done that but it still changes when i change what i sort it by